# Drop Down menu not creating Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, django

I am creating a website using Django in which it requires drop down menu.

obs_index.html:

```
{% block termscondobs %}
  <li>
    <a href="{% url 'terms-conditions' %}" class="waves-effect">
      <i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i> <span>Terms & Conditions</span>
      <i class="fa fa-angle-left float-right"></i>
    </a>
    <ul class="sidebar-submenu">
      <li><a href="{% url 'terms-conditions' %}"><i class="zmdi zmdi-star-outline"></i> OBS T&C</a></li>
      <li><a href="{% url 'terms-febs' %}"><i class="zmdi zmdi-star-outline"></i> Febs T&C</a></li>
      <li><a href="{% url 'terms-febs-events' %}"><i class="zmdi zmdi-star-outline"></i> Febs Events T&C</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
{% endblock %}
```

But it is not creating a drop-dwon-menu.The error is `Not Found: /terms/assets/js/popper.min.js`
Why is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the path

> /terms/assets/js/popper.min.js

is not the actual path for your js file, or the popper.min.js does not exist.

You can replace

> /terms/assests/js/popper.min.js

with

> https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.1/esm/popper.min.js